# Поиск ссылки в строке (регулярные выражения)

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Подсчитать колчество слов в строке с помощью регулярных выражений
   Сформировать новую строку в которой будут слова повторяющиеся больше 2х раз и их количесвто.
2. Поиск ссылок в тексте

Извините что не даю свой код. Я не думаю что там вообще есть что-то похожее на правду

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под ссылкой? Свой код лучше приложите.

Comment: Под ссылкой я понимаю все с этим началом: [http://]

Comment: Ну, вот Вам и регулярка `r"http://.*"`. Находит всё с началом `http://`.